# installshield stop old process before install new version

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, installshield

I have a setup made with installshield 2012, framework 3.5 and I am generating a new setup. My problem is that my UpgradeCode had to be changed. So I need to Update mi .exe with a different UpgradeCode. 
My problem is tan when I have the old .exe versión running, the installation do not execute well and the .exe failed when execute. 
What I need to do is to **CONFIRM** that Old versión is not running before Install the new version. 
I have tried to include in my Installer class

```
public override void Install(IDictionary stateSaver)
{
      Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName(processID); 
      foreach (Process process in processes)
      {
            process.Kill();
            process.WaitForExit();
            process.Close();
      }
}
```

But it does not work.
Any Ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Is there a protocol for closing your process gracefully (e.g. closing the main window or a named pipe command)? process.Kill is brutal that it does not clean up kernel resources. You probably need a custom action to put the closing code in unless your process is a windows service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of killing without any notifications your application (which myight lead to your users losing unsaved data, etc...) you could [ask the user to close it and stop the installation of the new version until the old application is closed](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=27795#p70575).

The above link explains how to do it with another tool, but with the right set of custom actions it can be achieved in any setup authoring tool.